# Flash storage best for running bootcamp?

Tags: windows, bootcamp

I am going to buy an imac and will use windows via bootcamp a lot of the time. I was wondering if installing the windows partition on flash storage is possible at all and if so if it will make windows work much faster in the same way it makes OS X faster. I could not find an answer to this question anywhere else. Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear why you think SSD wouldn't speed up either OS. Is there some review or link you can share as to why you have this problem understanding if a faster disk would work faster than a slower disk?

Comment: I was just not sure if the flash storage would also work much better for windows bootcamp compared to a normal 5400 storage drive. I could not find any info if it would work similarly on a windows partition as on a mac partition. Thanks

Comment: Do you mind if I try to edit it a bit in hopes it helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enough space on your SSD go for it.

If you have Fusion drive and enough space for both systems, Mac allows two partitions on the flash part and one can be used for Windows with bootcamp. Go for it.

Anyway, OS in flash storage is a great improvement, OS type does not matter, they all acquire great speed boost.

You can find additional info here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5446?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US .